# How to get week value based on financial year in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have below dataset , I need to find the week number from the date given based on the financial year(e.g April 2013 to March 2014). For example 01AprXXX , should be 0th or 1st week of the year and the consequent next year March's last week should be 52/53. I have tried a way to find out the same( code is present below as well).

**`I am just curious to know if there is any better way in SAS to do this in SAS`**

. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if this question is redundant, in that case I would delete it at the earliest, although I search for the concept but didn't find anything.

Also my apologies for my English, it may not be grammatically correct.But I hope I am able to convey my point.

**DATA**

```
data dsn;
format date date9.;
input date date9.;
cards;
01Nov2015
08Sep2013
06Feb2011
09Mar2004
31Mar2009
01Apr2007
;

run;
```

**CODE**

```
data dsn2;
set dsn;
week_normal = week(date);
dat2 = input(compress("01Apr"||year(date)),date9.);
week_temp = week(dat2);
format dat2 date9.;

x1 = month(input(compress('01Jan'||(year(date)+1)),date9.)) ;***lower cutoff;
x2 = month(input(compress("31mar"||year(date)),date9.)); ***upper cutoff;
x3 = week(input(compress("31dec"||(year(date)-1)),date9.)); ***final week value for the previous year;

if  month(dat2) <= month(date) <= month(input(compress("31dec"||year(date)),date9.)) then week_f = week(date) - week_temp;

else if x2 >= month(date) >= x1 then week_f = week_normal + x3 - week(input(compress("31mar"||(year(date)+1)),date9.)) ; 
run;
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INTCK` and `INTNX` are your best bets here.  You could use them as I do below, or you could use the advanced functionality with defining your own interval type (fiscal year); that's described more in the documentation.

```
data dsn2;
set dsn;
week_normal = week(date);
dat2 = intnx('month12.4',date,0);  *12 month periods, starting at month 4 (so 01APR), go to the start of the current one;
week_F = intck('week',dat2,date);  *Can adjust what day this starts on by adding numbers to week, so 'week.1' etc. shifts the start of week day by one;
format dat2 date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am eger to know , how to change this interval type? Please can you just point me to documentation(If it is not much of a problem to you). I would love to understand the cocept of it Thanks

Comment: @KabirPradeep Start with the [INTNX documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212700.htm), and then once you understand that, see the [INTERVALDS= SYSTEM OPTION](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003252593.htm).